# VB.Net Updating MySQL With Unique Key

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm writing to a MySQL database with a unique key. Ideally if a row with that key already exists I'm able to just update the columns I want to update. Looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO read_initial(column1,column2) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column1 = VALUES(column1value);
```

I've been trying to find the vb.net variation for this. At the moment I'm running a truncate and writing everything in again but that's obviously not ideal.

At the moment for the insert I'm using:

```
Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(myBuilder.ConnectionString)
                                Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
                                    With sqlCommand
                                        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO read_initial (`column1`, `column2`,) values (@column1value,@column2value)"
                                        .Connection = SQLConnection
                                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@column1", "column1value")
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", column2value)
```

I have tried changing the CommandText to

```
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO read_initial (`column1`, `column2`,) values (@column1value,@column2value) ON DUPLICATE KEY (`column1`) values (@column1value)"
```

But this doesn't seem to be right. I'd appreciate any pointers on this. My only other fallback is to send everything to a Python script by socket and let it handle the insert but that seems pretty roundabout when it is probably just syntax I have wrong here.

Comment: 'This doesn't seem to be right'. Could you explain why not? Do you get errors or is the record not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is pretty much the same whether you type this in the console or in VB.NET The sql command should look like

```
INSERT INTO read_initial (`column1`, `column2`,) values (@column1value,@column2value) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  `column1` = values(column1)
```

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET 'column1' = values('columndata') as line 1. I have a Python script updating the same DB so it has to be something I'm doing wrong with the .net syntax.

Comment: oops and extra SET crept in

Comment: glad to have helped. All the best with your project